# дайте возможность "вашему ребенку" / "для вашего ребенка"

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

"Сюжетно-ролевые игры у детей - это шанс улучшить воображение и творческое мышление. Давайте больше возможностей для Вашего ребенка!"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно "Давайте больше возможностей ДЛЯ ВАШЕГО РЕБЕНКА или ВАШЕМУ РЕБЕНКУ"?

Answer (score 1):

Слову "возможности" можно придавать разный смысл. Если ничего не менять, подразумевая смысл "то, что мы предлагаем - одна из таких возможностей (обратившись к нам, к нам вы даёте ему **возможность научиться** чему-то ещё)":

```
Да(ва)йте больше возможностей вашему ребёнку.
```

Если подразумевать смысл "то, что мы предлагаем, раскроет возможности (=**способности**) вашего ребёнка по-новому (вы такого метода ещё не знали, это вас удивит и т.п.)":

```
Раскройте новые возможности своего ребёнка.
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Глагол "давать" требует после себя беспредложного дополнения, т.е. предлог "для" в данном случае лишний, впрочем, как и любой другой предлог при этом глаголе.

ДАТЬ св. 1.2. ***(кому-чему)*** кого-что. Предоставить что-л.; обеспечить кому-л., что-л., сделать возможным для кого-л. Д. власть. Д. шанс кому-л.  Д. время на размышлени

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!